# ASN1 RFC1212 giving syntax error

Tags: asn.1

i am trying to compile ASN file using ASN.1 Studio.
the file i m using is 
RFC-1212.

i am getting 
"error A0120E: Parsing error: expecting typereference but found indextype."

anyone had the same problem.

if not please share the RFC-1212 mib file

Regards
Giri

Comment: If you read [RFC 1902](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1902.txt), you will find that "*These modules are written using an adapted subset of OSI's Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1)*". The key is the *adapted*, the SMI/MIB syntax is *not* (modern) ASN.1. Also please read the accepted answer at [ASN.1 compiler error token “SYNTAX” unexpected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255794/asn-1-compiler-error-token-syntax-unexpected)

Comment: thnks for info...i m trying to get the latest RFC-1212 with proper ASN.1 format but not able to, i dont want to modify the existing as it is from the RFC....any idea where can i get